# Getting a list of online users and saving to a variable? socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am trying to get a list of connected clients to a socket.io server, I have tried following: 
Using socket.io-client

```
io.socket.clients()
```

this gives:

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'clients' of undefined
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

look for this code:

```
var io              = require('socket.io')(2558);
```

var shortId      = require('shortid');

var clients          = [];

io.on('connection', function (socket) {

```
var currentUser;

socket.on('USER_CONNECT', function (){

    console.log('Users Connected ');
    for (var i = 0; i < clients.length; i++) {


        socket.emit('USER_CONNECTED',{

            name:clients[i].name,
            id:clients[i].id,
            position:clients[i].position

        });

        console.log('User name '+clients[i].name+' is connected..');

    };

});

socket.on('PLAY', function (data){
    currentUser = {
        name:data.name,
        id:shortId.generate(),
        position:data.position
    }

    clients.push(currentUser);
    socket.emit('PLAY',currentUser );
    socket.broadcast.emit('USER_CONNECTED',currentUser);

});

socket.on('disconnect', function (){

    socket.broadcast.emit('USER_DISCONNECTED',currentUser);
    for (var i = 0; i < clients.length; i++) {
        if (clients[i].name === currentUser.name && clients[i].id === currentUser.id) {

            console.log("User "+clients[i].name+" id: "+clients[i].id+" has disconnected");
            clients.splice(i,1);

        };
    };

});

socket.on('MOVE', function (data){

    // currentUser.name = data.name;
    // currentUser.id   = data.id;
    currentUser.position = data.position;

    socket.broadcast.emit('MOVE', currentUser);
    console.log(currentUser.name+" Move to "+currentUser.position);


});
```

});

console.log("------- server is running -------");

Answer (score 0):

In the latest socket.io, `io.socket.clients()` requires a callback passed to it and it will call that callback asynchronously:

```
io.socket.clients(function(err, connectedIds) {
    if (!err) {
        // connectedIds is an array of connected socket ids
    }
});
```

I have no idea why this info is only available via `.clients()` as an async callback because if you look at the code for this function, there is no async operation involved in retrieving the data.  Maybe there is some async operation anticipated or maybe it has something do do with things like the redis adapter used with clustering.

---

This same information is available synchronously in an object form:

```
var clients = io.sockets.connected;
```

This will be an object where the key is the socket.id for each connected socket and the value is the socket object.

So, you could synchronously get the same array of connected socket ids like this:

```
var connectedIds = Object.keys(io.sockets.connected);
```

Or, you could turn that into an array of connected socket objects like this:

```
var connectedSocketArray = Object.keys(io.sockets.connected).map(function(id) {
    return io.sockets.connected[id];
});
```